# /bin/ls sorts differently than just ls

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

```bsh
$ ls |sort
xyz-0.0.1-1554490900.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554745305.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554751021.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1555513460.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1555951745.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554323568.rpm

$ /bin/ls |sort
xyz-0.0.1-1554323568.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554490900.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554745305.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1554751021.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1555513460.rpm
xyz-0.0.1-1555951745.rpm

$ which ls
alias ls='/bin/ls --color'
        /bin/ls
```

Note that the sorting is different between the two commands (`ls |sort` results in incorrect sorting). This must be due to the color flag, but why?

Comment: To sort the output of `ls`, in many cases, you may found useful to specify directly the `-v` option: `ls -v `. Better to avoid the deprecated and risky _parsing_ of its output... In many modern distributions the alias of `ls` is directly set to `/bin/ls --color=auto`, as they suggest you in an answer.

Comment: The thing you're missing is how ANSI colour codes are signalled in a terminal. I'm not sure if it's constant or varies between terminals, but for me red can be triggered by printing `\033[91m`. Once you imagine the colour codes that are output by `ls` (normally consumed by the terminal), you can see why your sort would break (and then, the terminal strips them out so you can't see why the sort broke). I'm guessing the results were grouped by colour, _then_ sorted by name?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do:

```
/bin/ls --color > file1
/bin/ls > file2
```

and compare content, you'll see the difference.

Aliasing `ls` to `/bin/ls --color=auto` is likely better idea, it will stop `ls` from using color codes when not writing directly to terminal (like when piping to next program or writing to a file).

Comment: Thank you. I assume this is just a "known thing" and people understand ls + sorting should be done directly via `/bin/ls` vs. `ls`.

Comment: @JoshM. Well, sorting should be done by `ls` itself, if possible. Sorting with `sort` is *parsing*, [not recommended in general](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @JoshM., rather than using `/bin/ls`, change your alias to what Tomak suggested and you will get the better behavior automatically.

Comment: @JoshM. You can also use `\ls` for an unaliased `ls` or `command ls` for `/bin/ls`.

Comment: Yes, @Freddy, very true.  But, using `alias ls='/bin/ls --color'` is just a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @JoshM.: Yes, it's basically just a "known thing".  The main use-case for `ls --color` is piping into `less` or whatever other pager.  Of course it causes a problem in other cases, that's why `--color=auto` instead of `--color=always` exists.  Using it when piping into something that will parse `ls` output is best avoided.  (Or better, normally avoid parsing ls output entirely, except maybe for quick interactive use when you're ok with it maybe not working depending on special filenames. 
 Use tools like `find` or `stat`, or glob expressions, if you want to write robust commands.)

Comment: How does this answer answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 25):

In the sorted colored output `ls|sort`, we can see that the last line `xyz-0.0.1-1554323568.rpm` is the first line
of the non-colored output. The other lines are sorted equally.

If we have at a look at the colored escape codes (non-sorted), we can see that the first
line starts with a different escape code `^[[0m`. This is causing the wrong order when sorted (`^[[01` before `^[[0m`).

```
$ /bin/ls --color xyz* | cat -A
^[[0m^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1554323568.rpm^[[0m$
^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1554490900.rpm^[[0m$
^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1554745305.rpm^[[0m$
^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1554751021.rpm^[[0m$
^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1555513460.rpm^[[0m$
^[[01;31mxyz-0.0.1-1555951745.rpm^[[0m$
```